# Is there a point, besides organization, of using object properties instead of variables?

Tags: javascript, object

I've only been using for a month so sorry if this is a dumb question, but are there actually any practical benefits of for example saying

```
var object = {
  x: x,
  y: y,
  z: z
}
```

instead of simply declaring the value as variables

```
var x = x, y = y, z = z;
```

Comment: If you encapsulate your variables, they won't interfere with other scripts.

Comment: Yes, there are many reasons to use an object, but if a variable does the job, you've probably not encountered them yet.

Comment: Assuming your objects here represents a point. What would you do if you need two points? Or 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects first come in handy when you want to organize elements together.

If you are working with a location in space, you can create a `point` that keeps `x`, `y`, and `z` together:

```
var point = {
  x: 0,
  y: 1,
  z: -2
};

// Move
point.x += 1;
```

Now you have one object (`point`) that tells you a little about itself. You don't have to remember which things go together to make up your `point`, because they are together on the object.

They become even more important when you start working with *arrays* of these objects, which people sometimes refer to as *collections* (though not everyone).

```
var ships = [];
// Add some points to the array
ships.push(point1);
ships.push(point2);
```

Now each "ship" in the collection has it's own `x`, `y`, and `z`.

There are plenty of places where it makes sense to use a `var` instead of an object property. Most of these are inside a function, where you need to hold onto a value for a little while, and don't need other people to know about it.